# How to Initialize EigenMatrix from json or list of float strings?

Tags: json, c++11, eigen

I have :

```
Eigen::MatrixXf feature(1000,512);
```

and json :

```
[0.035114631056785583, 0.008220021612942219, -0.0018898098496720195, -0.10943937301635742, 0.03327044099569321, 0.0637984350323677, -0.04793999344110489, -0.0251377634704113, -0.042602453380823135, 0.06513188034296036, 0.04789276421070099, -0.04806295037269592
............]
```

512 float number.

How can I initialize `Eigen::MatrixXf feature(1000,512);` each row with above json?

After initialization is eigen-Matrix continues ?

Answer (score 0):

I do it one by one...

feature(0,x) = float(oenstring)

and for next.

any easy way?

Comment: Hello, @Prometheus. I meet the problem. Do you have any easy way. And how do you convert the matrix in eigen to json.